# Contact Layout errors after upgrade

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, contact-layout-editor

After upgrading civicrm from 5.38 to 5.46.2 on wordpress, also upgrading half a dozen extensions and upgrading wordpress I get the following errors from contact layout editor, on the contact summary editor or on the contact page if the extension is enabled.  Uninstalling and reinstalling contact editor did not fix the problem, nor did wiping the cache.  What to do?  What does this mean?

[the beginning of the errors are cut off by the wordpress menu]

pplied for foreach() in /home/railvermont/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.contactlayout-2.0.6/CRM/Contactlayout/BAO/ContactLayout.php on line 440

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/railvermont/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.contactlayout-2.0.6/CRM/Contactlayout/BAO/ContactLayout.php on line 440

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/railvermont/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.contactlayout-2.0.6/CRM/Contactlayout/BAO/ContactLayout.php:440) in /home/railvermont/www/www/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 9

thank you

Comment: Is this the same issue? https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.contactlayout/issues/101